# web scraping but an element does not have a class or an attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and for my first project, I have to scrape a website that sells used cars. The main page of this website shows main details such as the name of the car, price, and km, but if I click on any of theses cars it takes me to a more detailed page where I can find other information such as the color, etc. For the main page everything is good, but on the detailed page when I inspect the page all the elements I need do not have a class or an attribute. I'm using python, BeautifulSoup. Does anyone have any solution?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define a list to store the information for each car
car_info = []

# Define the headers to use for the request
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

# Create a session to store the headers
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

# Loop through the pages with the car listings
for page_num in tqdm(range(1, 25)): # To get all cars, set the range to 266
    # Make a GET request to the URL for the current page
    url = f'https://www.automobile.tn/fr/occasion/{page_num}'
    page = session.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    # Find all the car listings on the page
    car_listings = soup.find_all("div", class_="occasion-item")

    # Loop through each car listing
    for listing in car_listings:
        # Extract the title and price of the car
        title = listing.find("h2").text.strip()
        price = listing.find("div", class_="price").text.strip()

        # Extract the KM and year of the car
        year = listing.select_one('li[class="year"]').text.strip()
        km = listing.select_one('li[class="road"]').text.strip()

        # Extract the boite information
        boite = listing.find("li", class_="boite").text.strip()

        # Find the link to the detailed page for the car
        detailed_page_link = "https://www.automobile.tn" + listing.select_one("a")["href"]

        # Make a GET request to the URL for the detailed page
        detailed_page = session.get(detailed_page_link)

        # Parse the HTML content of the detailed page
        detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(detailed_page.content, "html.parser")

        # Extract the color, fuel, carrosserie, and puissance_fiscale information
        color = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="color").text.strip()
        fuel = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="fuel").text.strip()
        carrosserie = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="carrosserie").text.strip()
        puissance_fiscale = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="puissance_fiscale").text.strip()

        transmission = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="transmission").text.strip()

        # Add the information for the car to the list
        car_info.append((title, price, km, year, boite, color, fuel, carrosserie, puissance_fiscale))


df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['title', 'price', 'year', 'km', 'color', 'carrosserie', 'puissance_fiscale', 'boite', 'fuel', 'transmission'])
df.to_csv('various_cars.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

this is my code everything works fine until the part of the color, fuel etc. This is the error i'm getting:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8568\2004631293.py in <module>
     51 
     52         # Extract the color, fuel, carrosserie, and puissance_fiscale information
---> 53         color = detailed_soup.select_one('div[itemprop="color"]').text.strip()
     54         fuel = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="fuel").text.strip()
     55         carrosserie = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="carrosserie").text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS selector?

Comment: yes but nothing seems to work..

Comment: # Extract the color, fuel, carrosserie, and puissance_fiscale information
color = detailed_soup.select_one('div[itemprop="color"]').text.strip()
fuel = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="fuel").text.strip()
carrosserie = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="carrosserie").text.strip()
puissance_fiscale = detailed_soup.find("div", class_="puissance_fiscale").text.strip()
here's my trial with css selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include a link to a page as well as a screenshot or snippet of the source html that led you to use the `div[itemprop="color"]` / `div.fuel` / `div.carrosserie` / `div.puissance_fiscale` selectors? I only inspected [/peugeot/208/84502](https://www.automobile.tn/fr/occasion/peugeot/208/84502) on my browser, but I couldn't find any of them there which means at least SOME of the sites don't have any elements that match these selectors.

If you're not sure that your target element will be found, you should check for `None` before trying to extract text like in the function below. <sub>(It's a simplification of `selectGet` from [this set of functions](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u).)</sub>

```py
def selectTxt(tagSoup, selector='', defaultVal=None):
    el = tagSoup.select_one(str(selector).strip()) if selector else tagSoup
    return defaultVal if el is None else el.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

So, using **`color = selectTxt(detailed_soup,'div[itemprop="color"]')`** would avoid raising error, but would also just return `None` for the page that I inspected. The solution below uses the function but also just loops to get all items from the [specs preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsyTw.png) of the listing, the [info section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWtCy.png) of the details page, and the [technical details section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGx1v.png) (which has the color btw) of the details page.

```py
firstPg, lastPg = 1, 25
car_info = [] ## AS BEFORE
renameKeys = {
    'Kms': 'Kilométrage', 'Localité': 'Gouvernorat', 'Boîte vitesses': 'Boîte'
}

headers = { ## AS BEFORE
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
session = requests.Session() ## AS BEFORE
session.headers.update(headers) ## AS BEFORE


for page_num in tqdm(range(firstPg, lastPg+1)): 
    url = f'https://www.automobile.tn/fr/occasion/{page_num}' ## AS BEFORE
    page = session.get(url) ## AS BEFORE
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser") ## AS BEFORE
    car_listings = soup.find_all("div", class_="occasion-item") ## AS BEFORE 

    for listing in car_listings:
        liDets = { k: selectTxt(listing, s) for k, s in [
            ('title','h2'), ('price','div.price'), ('description','p')] }
        
        sPrvw_sel = 'span.name~span.value'
        for spec in listing.select(f'ul.specs-preview>li:has({sPrvw_sel})'):
            k = selectTxt(spec,'span.name:has(~span.value)').strip(':').strip()
            liDets[renameKeys.get(k,k)] = selectTxt(spec,sPrvw_sel)
        
        listingLink = listing.select_one('a[href]')
        if not listingLink: ## JUST IN CASE
            car_info.append(liDets)
            continue
        detailed_page_link = "https://www.automobile.tn" + listingLink["href"] 
        detailed_page = session.get(detailed_page_link) ## AS BEFORE
        detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(detailed_page.content, "html.parser") ## AS BEFORE

        for info in detailed_soup.select('div.infos>ul>li:has(label~span)'):
            k = selectTxt(info,'label:has(~span)').strip(':').strip()
            liDets[renameKeys.get(k,k)] = selectTxt(info,'label~span')

        tblSel = 'table[data-index="main"]:has(thead~tbody>tr:only-child)'
        for spec in detailed_soup.select(tblSel):
            k = selectTxt(spec,'thead').strip(':').strip()
            liDets[renameKeys.get(k,k)] = selectTxt(spec,'tbody>tr') 
        
        # phoneSel = 'div.infos>ul>li>span:has(i.fa-phone-alt)'
        # liDets['phone'] = selectTxt(detailed_soup, phoneSel)
        # liDets['details_link'] = detailed_page_link
        car_info.append(liDets)
```

Use `firstPg` and `lastPg` to set which pages to scrape, and `renameKeys` to change any column names that are scraped from the page with *`k= selectTxt...`*. [The 3 I've already set are just to not have duplicate columns with different names from overlaps between the specs preview and the details page.] With **`lastPg=2`** I get [image: df with 24 rows]

---

Btw, if you uncomment the last 3 lines and add two more `for` loops to also include the [bottom of the info section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmnpI.png) and the [collapsed] [equipments section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iBoh.png):

```py
        for desc in detailed_soup.select('div.description>p:has(b+br)'):
            k = selectTxt(desc,'b:has(+br)').strip(':').strip()
            desc.select_one('b:has(+br)').replace_with('') # !THIS EDITS detailed_soup
            liDets[renameKeys.get(k,k)] = desc.get_text(' ', strip=True)

        for e,eq in enumerate(detailed_soup.select('table[data-index="add"]')):
            k = selectTxt(eq,'thead',f'Equipements {e}').strip(':').strip()
            liDets[renameKeys.get(k,k)]=[selectTxt(x) for x in eq.select('td')]

        phoneSel = 'div.infos>ul>li>span:has(i.fa-phone-alt)'
        liDets['phone'] = selectTxt(detailed_soup, phoneSel)
        liDets['details_link'] = detailed_page_link
```

then the DataFrame might have [7 more columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7phc.png) and you'll have collected pretty much all the data available on the details page [except for the comments].

If you want the comments as well, you can target them with the [`.dsq-widget-comment`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rPUq.png) selector

```py
        cmntList = detailed_soup.select('.dsq-widget-comment>p:only-child')
        liDets['comments_list'] = [selectTxt(x)for x in cmntList]
```